# Проблема со сходом на сайт

Tags: joomla, warning, http, php

Warning: fopen() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/u216727/evitex.ru/www/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/sh404sef.class.php on line 975

Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/u216727/evitex.ru/www/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/sh404sef.class.php on line 977

Warning: feof(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/u216727/evitex.ru/www/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/sh404sef.class.php on line 980

Пожалуйста, скажите, что я должен делать?
Я понимаю, я могу это исправить с помощью FTP
где я могу найти IP-адрес хоста Joomla, для того чтобы войти в FTP
У меня есть только логин / пароль от админ-панели сайта, и то я не могу зайти, пишет ошибку так бы исправил бы через Extplorer
Вчера только добавил пару картинок на сайт, а сегодня уже не работает

Comment: а логин/пароль куда вводите?

Comment: Ввожу в FTP клиенте, но там не подключается, щас пытаюсь пытаться узнать реальный пароль с логином от FTP, так как существующие не подходят, а подходят только к админ панеле, но я не могу зайти в нее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Админ панель и ftp вам не поможет, обратитесь в техническую поддержку Мастерхост за помощью из cp.masterhost.ru.

Первая ошибка: "fopen() has been disabled for security reasons" говорит о том что, в php.ini директива allow_url_fopen = 0, чтобы работало нужно чтобы была 1.

Сами вы этот файл не отредактируете, за исключением случая когда вы сами собирали php на площадке.

Comment: Большое спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста это из за чего могло произойти? вчера все работало, сегодня уже нет. моя ошибка какая то?

Comment: Скорее всего сам Мастерхост изменил эту директиву в файле, например при обновлении ПО на сервере, т.е. вашей вины тут нет, по крайней мере по 1 ошибке, устранив её я думаю и остальные исчезнут.